# Secant_it method gives #VALUE! error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a code in VBA on Excel that uses the Secant Method to converge to a single root. `x0` is the first guess and `x1` is the second. For some reason every time I enter `Secant_it` into an Excel cell I get `#VALUE!`. I know the issue is not with Secant because when I enter it into a cell I get a correct number for the first value. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Function Secant(x0, x1)
    Dim x_new As Double
    x_new = x1 - f(x1) * (x1 - x0) / (f(x1) - f(x0))
    Secant = x_new
End Function

Function Secant_it(x0, x1)
    Dim x_new As Double
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 1
    x_new = Secant(x0, x1)
    While j < 21
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x_new
        x_new = Secant(x0, x1)
        j = j + 1
    Wend
        Secant_it = x_new
End Function
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout `f()` is a Function. `f = (Exp(x / 10) * Cos(x)) - (x ^ 2)`

Comment: have you thought about setting a break point @ the start of the function and then stepping through each line and calculation to make sure each variable is the value you're expecting it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your functions to these

```
Function Secant(x0, x1)
    Dim x_new As Double
    Dim a As Double, b As Double

    a = f(x1)
    b = f(x0)

    x_new = x1 - a * (x1 - x0) / (a - b)
    Secant = x_new
End Function

Function Secant_it(x0, x1)
    Dim x_new As Double
    Dim j As Integer

    j = 1
    x_new = Secant(x0, x1)
    While j < 21
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x_new
        x_new = Secant(x0, x1)
        Debug.Print x_new
        j = j + 1
    Wend
        Secant_it = x_new
End Function

Function f(x)
    f = (Exp(x / 10) * Cos(x)) - (x ^ 2)
End Function
```

I noticed you are getting `#VALUE!` because the function breaks after `j = 9` because `a` and `b` in `Secant` become `0`. So division by `0` breaks the `Secant` function and you get the error.

For testing purpose I took `=Secant_it(2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

Your test of convergence is causing an overflow, because after a certain number of iterations, x0 and x1 become so close that f(x1)-f(x0) is too small.

You should change the convergence test into checking if the difference between x0 and x1 is below the desired precision.

```
Function Secant_it(ByVal x0 As Double, ByVal x1 As Double)
    Dim x_new As Double
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 1
    x_new = Secant(x0, x1)
    'While j < 21
     While Abs(x1 - x0) > 0.000001 ' or any precision you desire
        x0 = x1
        x1 = x_new
        x_new = Secant(x0, x1)
        j = j + 1
    Wend
        Secant_it = x_new
End Function
```